# Converting string to int in Fortran

Tags: string, type-conversion, fortran

I am relatively new to Fortran and could not figure out how I can convert a string to an integer. An example:

```
integer x
character*5 st
st = '12abo'
x = st(1:2)
```

but seemingly this does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the read statement (analogous as what one would do in C with sscanf).

Comment: @albert I am sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Study the read statement and the format statement (something like `read(st,'(I2)') x`)